# Install MongoDB on Fedora

Tags: fedora, mongodb

So, I've heard that fedora doesn't include mongoDB in it's repos, and mongoDB official site doesn't provide Feodora images either.

I've tried using RHEL repo, as [workaround](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/how-to-install-mongodb-with-openssl-3-support-on-fedora-39/), but it throws some SSL error. And anyways, mirrors don't work currently. I don't know.

I need mongoDB for following through tutorial.

Error I get:

```
$ mongosh --version

mongosh: OpenSSL configuration error:
0068014FD77F0000:error:030000A9:digital envelope routines:alg_module_init:unknown option:../deps/openssl/openssl/crypto/evp/evp_cnf.c:61:name=rh-allow-sha1-signatures, value=yes
```

Comment: Which error exactly? Please [edit] the question and describe the exact step and any error message in full.

Comment: @ChanganAuto on `mongosh --version`, edited

Comment: https://www.mongodb.com/community/forums/t/openssl-error-when-starting-mongosh/243323/2

Comment: You are using Fedora, which accepts `RPM`'s. See [How To Install MongoDB in Fedora 36/35](https://tecadmin.net/install-mongodb-on-fedora/).  Note that the Fedora Version in the Title is irrelevant.

Comment: Many prerequisites are required and lots of disk space, memory, and time, but I compile it from source and it works great.